# Vue3 JS render and display dynamic images

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

### I am using:

Vue3, Node Express, MongoDB,node v18.13.0 (npm v8.19.3)

I have an error while I am trying to display images once I have them Uploaded

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './1678727136096_y62lf5CclYk6gTc.png'
at webpackContextResolve (app.js:2285:11)
at webpackContext (app.js:2280:11)
at Proxy.imageRoute (ProtokolAnschauen.vue?4b51:293:1)
at eval (ProtokolAnschauen.vue?4b51:108:1)
at renderList (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2912:1)
at eval (ProtokolAnschauen.vue?4b51:106:1)
at renderList (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2912:1)
at Proxy.render (ProtokolAnschauen.vue?4b51:33:1)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:898:1)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5702:1)
```

On Page "ProtokolErstellen" I upload all my images, store theire name in DB (MongoDB) via Node Express, then I press a button "preview" via

```
this.$router.push(/protokol_list/${this.currentPrtokolId}/In bearbeitung, { withCredentials: true })
```

I have an extra page in "ProtokolAnschauen"

Where I connecte and get all data from DB

```
async fetchItem(id) {await axios.get(${API_BACKEND_URL}list_display/protokol/${id})
.get(http://localhost:4999/list/protokol/${id}`).then(response) => {try {... SOME CODE})},
```

This function is executed once page is mounted

```
`mounted() { this.fetchItem(this.protokolId)    
this.containerBorder = ref('2px solid black');
this.containerMargin = ref('8rem');
}`
```

And always when I trying to "preview" images, I face this error

!!!BUT if I force to reload page, everything works fine, and all images are displayed without any issue

All images are stored in: "@/assets/"

Images are disaplayed via VUE

```
<img :src="imageRoute(image)" @error="imageLoadError" class="img-fluid" :alt="image" />
```

with function:

```
imageRoute(img) {return require(@/assets/${img})}
```

I am sure for 200% connection with DB is OK
Directory and root is FINE
I am checking if images has been instored and only after that, I provide option for user to click "Preview" button

I assume that the route cause is app.js file, webPackage -> 'var map'
where are listed all images, but I have no Idea how to force Vue, once images are uploaded this map

## Can someone help me with this?

Many thanks in advance!

I tried to display images with DIV
Tried to change return of

```
imageRoute(img){return require(@/assets/${img})},
```

tried to check if image exist
Used setTimeout for mounted() function

Also this - not working:

```
getImgUrl(pet) { var images = require.context('../assets/', false, /.png$/) return images('./' + pet + ".png") }
```

This also:
`getImgUrl(pic) {return require('../assets/'+pic) }`

didn't work for me

```
<img :src="require(@/xxx/${name}.png)" alt class="icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be done simpler?

I don't think you really need `require` for images.

Am I wrong?

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      images: [
        'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e5c/mill-house-1637156.jpg',
        'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/810/highlander-1325292.jpg',        
        'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/3af/misty-dawn-1-1195229.jpg'        
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getImageSrc() {
       return this.images[this.index]
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
img { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  Index: <input type="number" min=0 max=2 v-model="index" /><br/>
  <img :src="getImageSrc" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: I trird, and unfortunatelly it doesn't work
I will add error image to my question so you will be able to see all mesages